# Repeater control. Adding a CssClass at runtime

Tags: asp.net, css, repeater

i am trying to add a css-class to table cells based on the value of a third column

My markup is...

```
       <ItemTemplate>
          <tr id="row">
             <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Won")%></td>
             <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Lost")%></td>
             <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Result")%></td>
          </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

If the value of the `Result` is 1, add an css-class to the `Won` table cell.

If the value of the `Result` is 2, add an css-class to the `Lost` table cell

I tried using the `ItemCreated` event of the repeater control and got totally lost!

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use repeater's ItemDataBound method.

**EDIT:**
When you want to change the class of `<td>`, you have to add attribute `runat="server"` to it. Your
markup may look like below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMyRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Won") %> </td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Lost") %> </td>
            <td runat ="server" id="tdResult"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Result") %> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And code:

```
protected void rptMyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlTableCell tdResult = e.Item.FindControl("tdResult") as HtmlTableCell;
        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Result").ToString() == "1")
        {
            tdResult.Attributes["class"] = "Won";
        }
        else if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Result").ToString() == "2")
        {
            tdResult.Attributes["class"] = "Lost";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, your help is gratefully appreciated but i am still missing something.. Your solution adds the class to the label control and not to the parent <td>. I would like this class to be added at the parent <td> that hosts the label control. Am i missing something?